# Magento 2.3 admin custom form ajax not working

Tags: ajax, backend, adminform, magento2.2.3

Custom form ajax submit data not working in magento 2.3
its working with magento 2.1 and 2.2.x versions.

> Error 401 (Unauthorized)
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401
>   (Unauthorized)

Please give any suggestion

Comment: Yes my post action url seems like abc.com/admin/test_test_admin/test/savecomment/key/394ec87e0d449df30ba207742412455be5bc856703abbf06797feedff4e1059f/
Its working already with magento 2 all versions expect latest version

Comment: @Zaheerabbas As passed form_key as post param issue has  been solved. Aabhar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add form key to your post param.

Magento validate `form_key` before process you action if it doesn't find form key in your form post data it will give authorization error or it may.

So it's highly recommended to add `form_key` param with your post data to make it success.